# Error caused by pytest arg value being treated as a test path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I run pytest from command line using the command:

```
python -m pytest tests --server_image default
```

where `--server_image` is an argument defined in conftest.py file:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
        parser.addoption("--server_image", action="store_true", default="build_image")
        parser.addoption("--other_attr", action="store_true", default="True")
        ...
```

with 2 possible string values `build_image` and `default`. `tests` is a directory with the tests. I got an error message `ERROR: file or directory not found: default`. So pytest treats `default` as path to the test directory and not as a value of the argument. When i do not pass any argument everything works. Pytest version 7.0.0, python 3.8.12. Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `conftest.py` file, `--server_image` is set to `action="store_true"`, which means the variable is expected to be in a boolean format that becomes `True` if you call `--server_image` on the command-line. When doing so, `--server_image` can take no additional arguments, so the `default` becomes a completely separate argument. It would be the equivalent of calling:

`python -m pytest default tests --server_image`

... which is NOT what you want because you'll get the error from `default` unless that's the name of a folder.

Instead, you should change your `conftest.py` file so that you use `action="store"` instead for `--server_image`. And you'll need to set a destination into the `dest` field. That will let you use `--server_image default` so that you can assign a value.

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--server_image",
        action="store",
        dest="server_image",
        default="build_image",
    )
    parser.addoption(
        "--other_attr",
        action="store",
        dest="other_attr",
        default=None,
    )
```